# android : Customize dropdown's radiobutton open from webview

Tags: android, drop-down-menu, webview

I am developing android application which is based on the webview. 
The page loaded in the WebView has dropdown. When I click on the drop down, a dialog appears(it is the native Android dialog).i want to apply my them for that dropdown dialog item. i have searched but solution not found for that.

FYI, I have implemented it in the native activity but not able to implement it in webview.I want dropdown alert like displayed in below image. 
Please help me, if anyone knows related to this issue.

[image]

Comment: you cannot change that

Answer (score 0):

You need to understand the concept of a Webview. It is just like a browser which you are loading inside your activity. Your other activities in the app can not interact with the webview. If you want to change the style of your dropdown for android's webview, use Media Queries in your website which will change the view of your website when loaded for smaller devices